# Add glow to button when an image is set as a background

Tags: android, image, button

Normally button on clik fills orange color. When I set some image as button's background, there is no action on clik. I'd like to add some glow when button is pressed.

Comment: ill post some code when i get the sdk installed on this computer, but you should be able to manually change the background image for the different states in the onClick listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html). Type this into a file and store it as **res/drawable/button_bg.xml**. Then create 4 images (button_press.png, button_focus.png, button_disabled.png and button.png) and last set your background to `button_bg`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_press" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focus" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button" />
</selector>
```

The "magic" behind this is that android will go from the top to bottom and use the first one matching your buttons state.

Comment: according to your code do I need individual button_bg for each button?

Comment: No, think of this as an image (It is a drawable just like any other image) that you can use whenever you want.

Comment: I have 6 buttons in my lauout, each of them has got an image set as background. If I set button_bg as a background it goes in image's place.